# How do you rate Confluence for its wiki, community, and Q&A functionality?

Tags: wiki, confluence, social-media

I am currently investigating enterprise social media tools that we can potentially use either with SharePoint 2010 or instead of it. Confluence is one of the tools I am looking at. It seems to have strong wiki functionality, but does it also offer other social media functionality such as, Communities, activity streams, blogging, micro blogging, Q&A, Ideation, rating, sharing, following etc? I am interested in anyone's experience or knowledge on this subject.

Answer (score 4):

Confluence is getting more and more social. At Atlassian Unite in Frankfurt on 3/20 i saw some interesting new features like the "I like" Button on pages, mentions with @ in every text element. share functionality, blogging, commenting and micro blogging is build in since version 3.5. I have four customers who switched from Sharepoint to Confluence because it's fun and it works. There are about 1000+ free and commercial plugins in the plugin exchange. There you'll find workflow plugins, plugin for surveys and other interesting stuff. An App Store is planned. I'm using Confluence for all the project stuff in our intranet.